# SQL Query remove duplicates from specific column

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to filter the query based on the result of 1 column, and I don't want any duplicate. This is the query:

```
SELECT T1."CardName", 
       T0."Dscription", 
       T0."DocEntry", 
       T1."FolioNum",    
       T1."DocTotal", 
       T1."DocDate",
       T2."SeriesName", 
       T1."Series" 
FROM INV1 T0  
INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" 
INNER JOIN NNM1 T2 ON T1."Series" = T2."Series" 
WHERE T1."DocTotal" > 1000 AND 
      T0."DocDate" between [%1] and [%2]
```

I want everything `T0."DocEntry"` to be my unique result, I tried distinct, but that doesn't work in the way I want.

```
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
| T1."CardName"| T0."Dscription" | T0."DocEntry" | ... | 
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
| name 1       | product1        | 3111          |     | 
| name 1       | product2        | 3111          |     | 
| name 2       | product3        | 3222          |     | 
| name 2       | product4        | 3222          |     | 
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
```

What I need

```
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
| T1."CardName"| T0."Dscription" | T0."DocEntry" | ... | 
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
| name 1       | product1        | 3111          |     | 
| name 2       | product3        | 3222          |     |  
+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+
```

Hope can you help me.

Comment: Upload your query with distinct

Comment: I believe that you are missing something here. The example that you have uploaded has only distinct entries if you consider the T0."Dscription"  column (because you have two products with the same name). How can you tell the difference between product 1 and product 2? I mean why did you choose product 1 as your result?

Comment: Thank you Felipe, that was actually the column that was giving me problems, exactly for the reason that you say, after segregate (or remove) that column, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use (fake)  aggregation  function

```
  SELECT 
      T1."CardName"
      ,min( T0."Dscription")
      , T0."DocEntry"
  FROM INV1 T0  
  INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" 
  INNER JOIN NNM1 T2 ON T1."Series" = T2."Series" 
  WHERE T1."DocTotal" > 1000
  AND T0."DocDate" between [%1] and [%2]
   GROUP BY  T1."CardName", T0."DocEntry"
```

Comment: This actually work like a charm. This was my final code.

`SELECT T0."DocEntry", T1."CardName", MIN(T0."Dscription"), T1."FolioNum", T1."DocTotal", T1."DocDate",T2."SeriesName", T1."Series" 
FROM INV1 T0  INNER JOIN OINV T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" INNER JOIN NNM1 T2 ON T1."Series" = T2."Series" 
WHERE T1."DocTotal" > 1000 AND T0."DocDate" between [%1] and [%2]
GROUP BY T0."DocEntry", T1."CardName", T1."FolioNum", T1."DocTotal", T1."DocDate",T2."SeriesName", T1."Series"` Thank you! (I still need to know how to properly format here in stackoverflow, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the **distinct** feature in SQL to eliminate these duplicate rows. Just give it a quick Google search and you should be okay.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SALARY FROM CUSTOMERS
ORDER BY SALARY;
```

Quick example I found online.

Comment: Hi, I already use distinct, but Its filters another column, not exactly the one that I want. Thanks!